# Laravel apply pagination based on condition in query

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pagination

I am using laravel eloquent for db operation. I create a done function in that I want to apply my pagination if the variable has value if the variable value is not found then it should use laravel **get()** method. Here is my code

```
$query = DB::table('mytable')
->when($searchBy != null, function ($query) use ($searchBy) {
    return $query->where('mytable.id', '=', $searchBy)
        ->orWhere('orders.id', '=', $searchBy)
})
->orderBy('mytable.id', 'desc')
->paginate($recordsPerPage, ['*'], 'page', $pageNub);
```

I want to add pagination if `$recordsPerPage` variable is > 0, otherwise it should be use `get()` method

Comment: No i have not huge amount of data, around 400-500, do u have any solution for above one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would assign the builder to a variable and use some type of conditional here:

```
$query = DB::table('mytable')
    ->when($searchBy, function ($query, $searchBy) {
        return $query->where('mytable.id', '=', $searchBy)
            ->orWhere('orders.id', '=', $searchBy)
    })->orderBy('mytable.id', 'desc');

$result = ($recordsPerPage > 0) ?
    $query->paginate(...) :
    $query->get();
```